# Dropdown not working the second time when clicked using dom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, electron

I have made a navigation tab with buttons, and a side-button which displays a list of files when I click the nav button.

Visual representation:

```
check1 check2 check3  

dropdown (assuming check1 is clicked)
   1.txt
   2.txt
```

All the information comes up properly when I click on these checks in the console. but when I click on the button second time, it doesn't display any dropdown even though it shows correct information in console.

Code for function to create dropdown:

```
function add_pvt_dropdown(files) {
  const dropdown_div = document.getElementById("pvt_list_dropdown");
  //console.log(dropdown_div.childNodes[2])
  console.log("these are the child nodes \n:", dropdown_div.childNodes, "and this is the lenght", dropdown_div.childNodes.length)

  if (dropdown_div.childNodes[2])
    dropdown_div.removeChild(dropdown_div.childNodes[2])
  console.log(dropdown_div)
  const UL = document.createElement("ul"); 

  //files = localStorage.getItem('all_file_in_dir').split(',')
  if (typeof (files) === undefined && files == null) {
    alert("choose something")
  } else {
      UL.setAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu");
      UL.setAttribute("id", "pvt_option");
      UL.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", "dropdownMenuButton");
      files.forEach(val => {
        if (val.includes('CSV_')) {
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          var a = document.createElement('a');  
          
          a.setAttribute('class', "dropdown-item")
          a.setAttribute('id', val)
          li.appendChild(a);
          UL.appendChild(li)

          t = document.createTextNode(val);
          a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML + val;
          console.log(a.innerHTML)
        }
      });

      dropdown_div.appendChild(UL)
  }


}
```

HTML code

```
<div id="pvt_list_dropdown" class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" >
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButtonPvt" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            List
    </button>
</div>
```

Functionality: when I click on the navigation buttons, it takes all the files from a particular directory and shows as dropdown. As mentioned, it works just once, but when I click any other button or the same button twice, nothing is shows up in the dropdown.

Further information: I checked that it may be an arrangement issue with js and bootstrap but even correcting that doesn't help:

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

how information is shown for that element:

```
<div id="pvt_list_dropdown" class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButtonPvt" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">List</button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="pvt_option" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="f1.csv">f1.csv
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="f2.csv">f2.csv
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Edit:
information on how events are triggered:

the menu bar is called when DOM is loaded:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", menu_tags)

menu_tags is a function that will dynamically create the menu using create an element

function menu_tags() {

```
var check = ["check1",
"check2"
]
sub_checks = [
    "sub_checks1"
]

    var toadd = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var i;
      for (let i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        var newLi = document.createElement('a');
        newLi.href = "#" + check[i];
        newLi.innerHTML = check[i];
        newLi.id = check[i];
        newLi.className = "tablinks"
        newLi.onclick = function() {open(event, check[i])};
        
        // if(lib_verify_check[i] == "lib-checker"){
            
        // }
        toadd.appendChild(newLi);
    }

    document.getElementById("myTopnav").appendChild(toadd)

}
```

The open function will fetch the information for files for selected check

```
function open(event, checkname){
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace("active", "");
      }
      event.currentTarget.className += " active";   
      
      console.log(event.currentTarget.id)
      localStorage.setItem('selected_check', event.currentTarget.id)          
        // Exists.
        if(event.currentTarget.id){
          get_files()
          console.log("changed")
          
      }
      
      //localStorage.getItem('get_files')
}
```

in the get_files() function, all the file information will be stored and that information will be displayed in dropdown.

Please find the fiddle link below:
Note that get_files wont work in fiddle, this is for checking the functionality:

[fiddle_link](https://jsfiddle.net/mrinal18/0863ufbj/17/)

Comment: Do you first add events and then later create a menu with your function? If that is the case then you need to use event delegation.

Comment: event is added like this for these elements :

click on menu element -> fetch all the files from that particular information -> if the files are present then create the dropdown menu with those file name as information.

can you explain what is event delegation?

Comment: If you create an event like `$('...')on('click', function() {` and element is added later to the DOM you need to add the event to the parent that is already in the DOM and use `on('click', 'button', function() {` you've only shown the function, but don't explain how did you add the events. So this is just a guess. You don't add all information so you can't be sure.

Comment: @jcubic please find the events information under "edit" section.